# How to access the categories from this array to display on my custom page

Tags: categories, dump, shopware

I want to access page.categories.entities.elements->in that how to deal with these id's not getting

Here is the screenshot attached:

[image: here is the screenshot attached]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can do it like this also:

```
{% set categories = page.categories %}
 {% for category in categories %}
<li>{{ category.translated.name }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access it using **keys** filter in twig.

```
{% set keys = page.categories.entities.elements|keys %}
{% set data = page.categories.entities.elements[keys[0]] %}
{{ dump(data) }}
```